Get all csv from folders with pyspark
I have this path /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4
In folder4 we have folders like folder41, folder42.. and in each folder we have folders like
Year=2023
Year=2024
In each folder year we have csv files.
I wanna get all csv for folder4 for year=2023 using pyspark method. I wanna get without using for loop to get all csv.
Do you have answers? Please share with me.
Thank you

side note -- "Year=2024" seems like the underlying data is indexed at year column

Yes, the data is indexed on year=2024 or year=2023.

Use regex in path like below.
path = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder4[1-9]*/year=2023"

OR
path = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder4*/year=2023"

OR
path = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/*/year=2023"

spark.read.csv(path)

